# vim nerd tree plugin and dvorak keyboard layout

Tags: vim, layout, nerdtree, dvorak

i switch to dvorak layout, i remap keys in vim, but some keys in nerd tree plugin still work as for qwerty layout. How can i solve that?

Comment: Why do you have to remap the keys in vim? Changing the keyboard layout system-wide should do the trick.

Comment: i want to have movements keys on old place (d h t n in dvorak)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NERDTree plugin is very well documented.  A quick look at `:help NERDTree` shows that most (if not all) mappings are configurable and can be changed by setting global options.  It even provides an API to add your own custom mappings that show up in the NERDTree window's help system.